# Copying single file to selected subfolders

Tags: batch-file, copy

... specifically, my parent folder is called 'Tiles'. Within this folder are a hundred or more subfolders, each containing further subfolders of their own. Examples would be:

Tiles/zzOrtho1/textures
Tiles/zzOrtho1/terrain
Tiles/zzOrtho1/nav data
Tiles/zzOrtho2/textures
Tiles/zzOrtho2/terrain
... and so forth

I have a file in the Tiles parent directory called 'water.dds' and I want to copy it to every 'sub-subfolder' called 'textures', but no other folders present.

This batch script (found on this forum), when placed in the Tiles folder, will copy the file water.dds to every folder and subfolder within the Tiles parent folder:

```
 @echo off
    for /r "%CD%" %%f in (.) do (
      copy "water.dds" "%%~ff" > nul
    )
```

But I haven't been able to edit it so that the dds file is only copied into all the 'sub-subfolders' called 'textures'.

Alternatively, this copies the dds file, now contained in its own subfolder 'Tiles/water/' to a folder Tiles/Textures, but again, I can't see how to adapt this so that it looks for folders called 'Textures' one layer deeper in the folder structure, and copies water.dds to all of them..

```
for /D %%x in (textures.*) do copy "water" %%x
```

Can anyone kindly help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you do it (run inside parent directory "Tiles")

```
@echo off
for /D /r %%G in (*.*) do (
    if /I "%%~nxG"=="textures" copy "water.dds" "%%~G" > nul        
)
```

`%%~nxG` gives you the folder name (the part after the last /)

```
for /D /r %%G in (*.*) do ( ...
```

This iterates through every subfolder

Comment: You do not need the `"%CD%"` part as `for /R` uses the current directory as the root anyway (or you specify the root directory explicitly instead). I strongly recommend to add `/I` to `if`, because Windows treats dir./file paths/names case-insensitively; in addition, use quotes, like `if /I "%%~nxG"=="textures"`, to avoid spaces or some other characters to cause trouble. Finally, I think you have to provide the full path to the source file `water.dds`...

Comment: Thanks @aschipfl, edited :). It doesn't need the full path to the water.dds file because the file is in the directory where the batch file will run.

Comment: Great! Just keep in mind that the current working directory is not the same as the parent directory of the batch script; `%CD%` points to the current working directory, where `%~dp0.` points to the path file container...

Comment: Thank you both very much, that works just fine! Much appreciated - I am afraid my skills aren't quite up to your level.